# Ohm, find all records from array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ohm

I am looking for a way to find all Ohm affiliated objects with one query, by feeding it an array of attributes that are indexed. In Mongoid, this is done with something like:

```
Foo.any_in(:some_id => [list_of_ids])
```

ActiveRecord has the `find_all` family of methods.

I essentially want to be able to pull N records from the data store without calling find() 30 times individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass find an array or list of IDs:

```
Foo.find(1,2,3) or Foo.find([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not seem to work with the latest Ohm (1.1.1). I looked through the source and it seems you need to do something like `Model.all.send(:fetch, [1,2,3])`. Problem is... you have to call a private method.

I created an [issue](https://github.com/soveran/ohm/issues/69) to see if this is the right approach.

UPDATE: It was [just made](https://github.com/soveran/ohm/issues/69) public!